# Spark: Iterating through columns in each row to create a new dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

Let's say I have a dataframe like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+--+
|   ColA    |   ColB    |   ColC    |   ColD    |    ColE    |  |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+--+
| ''        | sample_1x | sample_1y | ''        | sample_1z  |  |
| sample2_x | sample2_y | ''        | ''        | ''         |  |
| sample3_x | ''        | ''        | ''        | sample3_y  |  |
| sample4_x | sample4_y | ''        | sample4_z | sample4_zz |  |
| sample5_x | ''        | ''        | ''        | ''         |  |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+--+
```

I want to create another dataframe that shows the relationship from left to right in each row, while skipping columns that have empty values. Also rows that only have 1 valid columnar record will be excluded. For example:

```
+-----------+------------+-----------+
|   From    |     To     |   Label   |
+-----------+------------+-----------+
| sample1_x | sample1_y  | ColB_ColC |
| sample1_y | sample1_z  | ColC_ColE |
| sample2_x | sample2_y  | ColA_ColB |
| sample3_x | sample3_y  | ColA_ColE |
| sample4_x | sample4_y  | ColA_ColB |
| sample4_y | sample4_z  | ColB_ColD |
| sample4_z | sample4_zz | ColD_ColE |
+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

I'm thinking the approach would be to write a UDF that contains this logic but I'm not entirely sure how I would return a completely new DF, as I'm used to UDFs just creating another column within the same DF. Or if there's another spark function that can handle this case easier than creating a UDF? Using pyspark if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use udf which takes an array argument and returns an array of structs, for example:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.show()
+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+
|     ColA|     ColB|     ColC|     ColD|      ColE|
+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+
|     null|sample_1x|sample_1y|     null| sample_1z|
|sample2_x|sample2_y|     null|     null|      null|
|sample3_x|     null|     null|     null| sample3_y|
|sample4_x|sample4_y|     null|sample4_z|sample4_zz|
|sample5_x|     null|     null|     null|      null|
+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+

# columns that get involved, will group them into an array using F.array(cols)
cols = df.columns

# defind function to convert array into array of structs
def find_route(arr, cols):
    d = [ (cols[i],e) for i,e in enumerate(arr) if e is not None ]
    return [ {'From':d[i][1], 'To':d[i+1][1], 'Label':d[i][0]+'_'+d[i+1][0]} for i in range(len(d)-1) ]

# set up the UDF and add cols as an extra argument
udf_find_route = F.udf(lambda a: find_route(a, cols), 'array<struct<From:string,To:string,Label:string>>')

# retrive the data from the array of structs after array-explode
df.select(F.explode(udf_find_route(F.array(cols))).alias('c1')).select('c1.*').show()
+---------+----------+---------+
|     From|        To|    Label|
+---------+----------+---------+
|sample_1x| sample_1y|ColB_ColC|
|sample_1y| sample_1z|ColC_ColE|
|sample2_x| sample2_y|ColA_ColB|
|sample3_x| sample3_y|ColA_ColE|
|sample4_x| sample4_y|ColA_ColB|
|sample4_y| sample4_z|ColB_ColD|
|sample4_z|sample4_zz|ColD_ColE|
+---------+----------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Using mainly Spark SQL:

```py
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
cols_df = df.columns
qry = " union ".join([f"""
select {enum_cols[1]} as From,
{cols_df[enum_cols[0] + 1]} as To,
'{enum_cols[1]}{cols_df[enum_cols[0] + 1]}' as Label from df where {enum_cols[1]} <> '' and {cols_df[enum_cols[0] + 1]} <> ''""" 
              for enum_cols in enumerate(cols_df) if enum_cols[0] < len(cols_df) - 1])
final_df = spark.sql(qry)
```

Comment: Is there supposed to be an f before the triple quote query? I get an error with that left in, after removing that and running I get a ParseException that starts with "\nno viable alternative at input 'select {'(line 1, pos 7)\n\n== SQL ==\nselect {enum_cols[1]} as From,\n-------^^^\n  {cols_df[enum_cols[0] + 1]} as To, '{enum_cols[1]}{cols_df[enum_cols[0] + 1]}' as Label where {enum_cols[1]} <> '' and {cols_df[enum_cols[0] + 1]} <> ''

Comment: Oh I see the f makes it a formatted string literal, hmm I'm still getting syntax errors with it included though

Comment: The f is for string interpolation, I just modified the answer to wrap two columns value in ''.  Does it work now or are you still getting an error? If so which one?

Comment: Yeah a syntax error pointing to the end of the triple quoted string

Comment: Going to just try constructing the equivalent sql via pyspark functions

Comment: @dl8 I have just tested it to make sure it works and update the relative code. The issue is that ```from df```  was missing from qry.

Comment: Still getting syntax errors, but I'm translating your logic to spark functions and I don't think its correct. It doesn't handle cases where there are gaps in the column, like if you look in my example, sample3_x pointing to sample3_y when they are 3 columns apart while the logic here is only looking at the next adjacent column without checking the later ones.